# New Centos7 install - AD logins are not asking for password

Tags: active-directory, centos7, password

Very strange one this.
I've built a new Centos7 server today, exactly the same way (I believe) as a tonne of others that I've done.
I use the 'realm join domain.name' command to join the server to our AD domain.

This command was successful as it always is, but when I try to login using AD creds I do not get prompted for a password! i.e. it logs me straight in to the server without requesting a password.

We do not use SSH keys in this environment so it is definitely not that. I've checked sshd_config and see no issues in there.
Here's a paste of some /var/log/secure messages from the server:

`Mar 23 09:09:00 kn-test-mdb sshd[1532]: Authorized to handsm@domain, krb5 principal handsm@DOMAIN.NAME (ssh_gssapi_krb5_cmdok)
Mar 23 09:09:00 kn-test-mdb sshd[1532]: Accepted gssapi-with-mic for handsm@domain from 10.16.23.24 port 60600 ssh2
Mar 23 09:09:00 kn-test-mdb sshd[1532]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user handsm@domain by (uid=0)`

Any help/direction on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Answered my own question!
Had to disable GSSAPIAuthentication in sshd_config.

Sorted now.

Comment: If the host you are connecting from have a valid kerberosticket it should not ask for password.

Comment: @machinist: Please post this as a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question! Had to disable GSSAPIAuthentication in sshd_config. Sorted now.